# Where to save configuration parameters in the Registry for future reference in updates

Tags: installation, windows-installer, registry, installshield

I'm developing a software installer and I need to know in which key of the registry I have to save the parameters of properties used for configuring the software.

I know thanks to InstallShield reference that I need to store these values in the registry, but if anyone have a better and cleaner solution please
describe that.

Comment: This is for WiX toolset, but the general approach should work for Installshield too: [The WiX toolset's "Remember Property" pattern](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/the-wix-toolsets-remember-property-pattern/)

Comment: Maybe list what parameters you need to store so we can see if the design is well-formed. Sometimes it is better to generate values on app-launch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you need to preserve certain values inside the Windows registry to be used by the software your installer installs. Usually software keep values in the registry under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` roots, depend on installation type ("For everyone" or "For current user only"). The path may looks like ...

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\{Vendor Name}\{Product Name}
```

You may open `regedit.exe` and have a look how other companies store applications values inside Windows registry.